# How to check if plugin icon is toggled?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I've created a plugin icon which can toggle and is connected to the `run()` function. At the moment, whenever a user clicks on the icon, it executes the `run()` function.

How could I make it so that it only executes this function when its toggle state [isChecked()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qaction.html#checked-prop)?

A simple example:

```
def add_action(self,icon_path,text,callback,checkable=False,enabled_flag=True,add_to_menu=True,add_to_toolbar=True,status_tip=None,whats_this=None,parent=None):
    icon = QIcon(icon_path)
    action = QAction(icon, text, parent)
    action.triggered.connect(callback)
    action.setEnabled(enabled_flag)
    action.setCheckable(checkable)

    if status_tip is not None:
        action.setStatusTip(status_tip)
    if whats_this is not None:
        action.setWhatsThis(whats_this)
    if add_to_toolbar:
        self.toolbar.addAction(action)
    if add_to_menu:
        self.iface.addPluginToMenu(
            self.menu,
            action)

    self.actions.append(action)
    return action

def initGui(self):
    icon_path = ':/plugins/Example/icon.png'
    self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Example'),
        callback=self.run,
        checkable=True,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

def run(self):
    print 'Plugin loaded.'
    #if checkable == True:
    #   print 'Checked'
    #else:
    #   print 'Unchecked'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of writing a conditional inside the `run()` function.

`QAction.triggered` SIGNAL sends the `checked` state to its connected SLOTs. Add the `checked` parameter to `run()` and write a conditional based on that state.

Every button click will still execute the `run()` function, but you could choose what code you want to be executed for each state.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add an alternative to [@GermánCarrillo's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/4972/germ%c3%a1n-carrillo) answer, you can also name the action (e.g. `self.iconAction = self.add_action(...)`) and call this inside the `run()` function:

```
def initGui(self):
    icon_path = ':/plugins/Example/icon.png'
    self.iconAction = self.add_action(
        icon_path,
        text=self.tr(u'Example'),
        callback=self.run,
        checkable=True,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

def run(self):
    print 'Plugin loaded.'
    if self.iconAction.isChecked():
        print 'Checked'
    else:
        print 'Unchecked'
```