# How to disconnect a signal when untoggling plugin icon?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Following on from this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227578/how-to-check-if-plugin-icon-is-toggled),  I've created a signal whereby when the plugin icon is toggled (or checked), the user can change the visibility of a layer which is connected to a function (`print_me`). This will print a simple message.

However, I've tried to disconnect this signal when the plugin icon is untoggled but I receive the following error:

> TypeError: 'function' object is not connected

Even though the function is connected as the message is still printed. How could I solve this?

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        ...

def run(self, checked):
    #################
    if not self.pluginIsActive:
        self.pluginIsActive = True
        if self.dockwidget == None:
            self.dockwidget = Example_dockDockWidget()
        self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)
    #################
    root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
    group = root.findGroup('Group')

    def print_me():
        print 'Message!'

    if checked:
        for layers in group.children():
            layers.visibilityChanged.connect(print_me)
    else:
        for layers in group.children():
            layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(print_me)
```

---

**Edit**:

Although a solution I posted involved putting the `print_me` function outside the class, I need this function to be **inside** the class. This is because, in my plugin, the function makes references to the QGIS interface such as printing values to the plugin's dockwidget.

If I incorporate a `try` method such as the following:

```
if checked:
    for layers in group.children():
        layers.visibilityChanged.connect(print_me)
else:
    for layers in group.children():
        try:
            layers.visibilityChanged.disconnect(print_me)
        except TypeError:
            pass
```

The error is ignored but if I toggle the icon again, the connection is made again. So it runs the `print_me()` function twice! I don't understand why a connection can be made when the icon is checked but when unchecked, it cannot be disconnected...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `print_me()` function should be a function on its own and not inside another. The following works:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        ...

    def print_me(self):
        print 'Message!'

    def run(self, checked):
        if checked:
            root.visibilityChanged.connect(self.print_me)
        else:
            root.visibilityChanged.disconnect(self.print_me)
```

*Annoyingly, this was the first thing I tested but for some reason kept failing. After having QGIS reinstalled recently and re-testing this approach, it works!*

---

Another method which also worked but is probably not as efficient is to move the function outside the *class*:

```
def print_me():
    print 'Message!'

class Example:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        ...
    def run(self, checked):
        if checked:
            root.visibilityChanged.connect(print_me)
        else:
            root.visibilityChanged.disconnect(print_me)
```